# multithreading in android

Tags: android, multithreading, client

I have an app in android,a kind of client-server in which the client has stored some gps data in Sqlite database and once connected with server it delivers it that data which at its turn stores it in it's own database for future manipulation!

Now the problem is that I have to create a server that accepts multiple clients and I cannot find a decent example in this way.I'm not using no services in combination with it!
Both my client and server are on android!!!!

I have already did the connection between client and server,but only with one thread(I mean my server can accept only one client at this moment!)

Is this suitable?

[How to implement simple threading with a fixed number of worker threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125333/how-to-implement-simple-threading-in-java)

Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request from the client to the server should be good enough. Encode the data in a suitable format (JSON/XML) and send it as a POST HTTP request. 
I don't understand why you want to write your own server. I would just use a PHP/Python script running with Apache to receive the POST request and store the data in a database (MySQL, PostGre).

On your Android device, you should put all your code in an AsyncTask. Android uses the standard Apache libraries to make the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

If server is Microsoft based, .net web service can be used that can be accessible from multiple Android clients and work with database.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your server is not on the Android device I guess, so I don't think the question is android related.</strike>

Check out [this example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html) of multithreaded server in Java and [this one](http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html) as well.

To communicate with database, see the [Java JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Those examples are in Java, because that's what I am used to, but any other language will fit as well.

Comment: Well, ignore my first line :) but it's even better - multithreaded server (as in the links I gave you) is still relevant and regarding sql DB: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db