# Thread in RoundRobin method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

Here is a sample code if the thread size is 3 means its ok. where i can manage the memory. if the thread size is 50 there the problem lies. i need to set threadsize as 5. finished thread should be reuse the by other

```
Thread[] TCreate = new Thread[iThreadSize]; 
for (int i = 0; i< TCreate.length; i++) {

    TCreate[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            lst.Add(this.getResult(url));
        }
    });
    TCreate[i].setName("URL"+i);
    TCreate[i].start(); }

for (int j = 0; j < TCreate.length; j++)
    while (TCreate[j].isAlive())
         Thread.sleep(10);
```

Can any one help what is use of setDaemon() method. what is purpose of Daemon
Please Help me.. Advance thanks

Comment: To format code, use the `{}` button in the editor, not the quote button.  I fixed it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java already includes methods for managing Thread pools.

calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` will generate a thread pool with 5 worker threads for you.

Afterwards you can just assign Runnables that will be executed by on of the Threads in the pool.

See also:

- [How to implement simple threading with a fixed number of worker threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125333/how-to-implement-simple-threading-in-java)
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 2):

`setDaemon` controls whether a thread is a daemon thread or not.  If daemon threads are still running when the program reaches the end of the main method, it does not keep the program from quitting.  Non-daemon threads (user threads) do keep the program from quitting.